# Can &hint= be disabled on forgot password links?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When a user tries to log in but fails with a bad password and then clicks the forgot password link, they are directed to a URL containing their PII email.

The hint is not injected until the link is clicked, so it can probably be fudged with some custom JS, but we would like to use configuration rather than customisation..

e.g.
`https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_customflow/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/forgotPassword?csrf_token=xxxx&tx=StateProperties=xxxx&p=B2C_1A_customflow&hint=blablablah@example.com`

This PII has potential to be captured/logged/etc, which we would really like to avoid.

So, can we turn that off?

Yes, we understand this is a convenience/quality-of-life feature to help clients, but revealing their PII  seems a poor trade-off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure AD B2C guidelines for using custom JS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-javascript-overview#guidelines-for-using-javascript) direct prohibit binding the click event on anchors/links, but we can use the mousedown event.

With that, we can use a JS snippet as below to clear the signInName field, and so prevent the link from containing the hint parameter:

```
$("#forgotPassword").mousedown(function () {
    $("#signInName").val("");
});
```

This addresses the issue with customisation, so now we wait to see if we can replace it with an official configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

If you initiate Password Reset by clicking on the "Forgot your password?" link at the sign-in page, clicking this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset user flow. Instead, the error code AADB2C90118 is returned to your application. Your application needs to handle this error code by running a specific user flow that resets the password. You should be able to handle the URL and forgot password from the application.

Comment: The code AADB2C90118 is returned to the application by what mechanism? From debug console, it comes via redirect /after/ the forgot password link hits Azure AD with the hint parameter